# Why should I declare a "private" function static when I can simply not put it in the header file?

Tags: c, header-files, private

I understand the `static` keyword is used for creating functions or variables which are "private" to the translation unit (the source file).

However, as far as I understand, in order to make sure a particular function or variable is not accessible from outside the `.c` file that it was declared in, I can simply *not* declare it in the corresponding `.h` file.

For example:

**f.c**

```
void public_func() {
    // ...
}

void private_func() {
    // ...
}
```

**f.h**

```
void public_func();

// no declaration of private_func
```

So why should I also declare `private_func` as `static`? Is that simply a convention or does it have a technical benefit over simply not declaring it in the `.h` file?

Comment: Because a non-static function will still be known to other object files in the linking process.

Comment: Functions have external linkage by default, so they can be "accessed" even if no prototype provided in the `h` file.

Comment: One could create a file, say, `g.c` and declare a prototype `void private_func();` and now it has access to your private function.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie But wouldn't the compiler yell at me when trying to compile a `.c` file which uses a function name it doesn't recognize?

Comment: It will yell at most a warning and will assume returning int.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Only in case one didn't bother to prototype it as Christian suggests.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Wasn't that officially removed from the C standard?  (Though gcc will still do it anyways, I believe)

Comment: OK: in some C file you could give a prototpe for the function and the compiler will be happy, even if you did not "officially" export it in a header file. To make it absolutely unavailable you _must_ declare it static and now the linker will not find it and yell an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that compilers work on "translation unit" basis, meaning one .c file and all the .h files it includes. So it is traditionally not able to detect naming collisions across the whole project.

So if you don't make it `static`, the function has "external linkage" per default. Meaning if have a function `private_func` and another translation unit in the same project is using the same name, you get namespace collisions during linking and linker errors.

It is also a matter of correctness - private functions/variables should simply not be accessible from the outside, neither intentionally nor accidentally.

Answer (score 1):

> I understand the static keyword is used for creating functions or variables which are "private" to the translation unit (the source file).

That's true.

> Is that simply a convention or does it have a technical benefit over simply not declaring it in the .h file?

There is a technical point here. Once compiler is done doing it's job it produces an object file. That file has a symbol table, which is later used by linker when the linker puts a program together from separate object files. `static` functions will not get into that table, so that direct references to that function from other object files will fail with "unresolved reference" error in the linking stage.

`Benefits`? Well you save some tiny space in you object file, linking stage will go faster, since there will be a smaller table to process. But that's tiny enough to not make a difference, unless we're talking about a made up case of thousands of functions with loooong names.

If you have a non-`static` function and you omit it's declaration in the header file, the function name still gets into a symbol table. And if I happen to know the declaration somehow (other than from the header) I can still call/reference the function directly from another translation unit, no linker error will happen.

Comment: Hi Igor. What do you mean by "And if I happen to know the declaration somehow (other than from the header)"? Do you mean if I declared the function myself inside the `.c` file?

Comment: @AvivCohn Eventually you'll have to do that. The answer to you question is "Yes, I mean if you declare the function yourself inside the `.c` file." Normally that's exactly what `#include <header.h>` does for you (if it contains the declaration).

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you write a library that consists of several `.c` and `.h` files. The clients of your library will need to use some of the header files to use your library. They should only see the public functions.

But for the implementaiton of your library, you might also use header files so functions in your library can call other (internal) functions.

So you end up with two types of declarations:

*For clients of your library*

```
void public_func();
```

*For internal use*

```
static void private_func();
```

Preferrably, the private and public declarations are in separate header files and the clients of your library only need to include the header files with public functions.